# Programmatically remove UILabel that has autolayout from View

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I parse Json data and I set it on some UILabels, What I want is that when there's no text for a specific label It has to be removed from the UIView, I tried with 2 methods but with no results because the labels has constraints.
What I tried is:

Set their frame to 0 and the height constraint to 0

```
CGRect noFrame = _prepTime.frame;

noFrame.size.width = 0;
noFrame.size.height = 0;
[_prepTime setFrame:noFrame];
prepTimeHeight = 0;
```

But the height of the UILabel still remains,

The I tried with:

```
[_prepTime removeFromSuperView];
```

With this one the UILabel gets removed but the interface changes since it has constraints and by removing the UILabel I destroy the layout.

Is there any method to remove the UILabel from the view even if it has constraints?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `hidden` if you don't want to affect all other subviews.

Answer (score 0):

When using layout constraint it's not a good idea to edit the frame of your element. Instead you should add a `IBOutlet property` for your `NSLayoutConstraint` and link it to the height constraint of your label in your storyboard, then edit the constant value of the `NSLayoutConstraint`.

Someting like that in your viewcontroller `@implementation`:

```
@property IBoutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myLabelHeightConstraint;
```

and later when you want to hide your label :

```
self.myLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Tried but the height still remains